# Having a UIButton be tapped in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with its cells all laid out.

I have this declared as a subview:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *aButton;
```

I then have that declared in each cell like so:

```
if (_aButton == nil)
{
    _aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
}

// Add in all _aButton info here

[self.contentView addSubview:_aButton];

// Call to button pressed for button

[_aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The button click method is like so:

```
- (IBAction) aButtonPressed:(UIButton *) sender
{
    // Code never gets heree
}
```

The `if(_aButton`== `nil) is needed since cells get reused.

How do I make this work now? Thanks.

Comment: What is actually wrong? The nil check has nothing to do with reuse unless you remove the button somewhere else.

Comment: why don't you use storyboard for collectionview with prototype cell?It better way to setting button on storyboard.

Comment: The frame is set fine and correct in the // add all aButton stuff here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add button action code before button added to view.... May be it will work .

```
 // Call to button pressed for button

[_aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Add in all _aButton info here

[self.contentView addSubview:_aButton];
```

Comment: not sure why but that switch allowed the button press to be called.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the way you are initializing the button is going to give you frame as 0,0,0,0 . So first give it a proper frame and title to be visible on the screen.

Then try tapping on that title and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you trying to achieve here, but the button is not working because you not setting it's position and size on the cell. It could be done by setting frame or layout constraints.

Try to set button frame:

```
_aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f);
```

You can also set background color for the button, just to make it visible on the cell:

```
_aButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Everything else is correct, button should work.